# How to add/combine SUM from 2 tables Oracle, Basic

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, aggregate-functions

I am very new to SQL,

I have 2 code like this

```
Select ID, SUM(Column1) AS Sum1
from table1

Select ID, SUM(Column1) AS Sum2
from table2
```

AS result of table1

```
ID------ Sum1  
001      20
003      10
004      5
```

AS result of table2

```
ID------ Sum2  
001      20
003      10
005      10
```

I would like show the result after joining this 2 tables like this, how can I wirte the code to show like below?

```
    ID------ Sum 
    001      40
    003      20
    004      5
    005      10
```

Thank you so much

Comment: your first queries would return an error, I assume a group by clause is missing in the example, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, SUM(COLUMN1)
FROM (
    SELECT ID, COLUMN1 FROM T1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, COLUMN1 FROM T2
)
GROUP BY ID;
```

note here that UNION ALL is used instead of UNION so you can show duplicated results

Answer (score 0):

You can `FULL JOIN` the two subqueries together (after adding a `GROUP BY` to each), and use `COALESCE()` to return the proper value:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.ID,b.ID) AS ID
     , COALESCE(a.Sum1,0)+COALESCE(b.Sum2,0) AS Sum
FROM (Select ID, SUM(Column1) AS Sum1
      from table1
      GROUP BY ID
     ) a
FULL JOIN (Select ID, SUM(Column1) AS Sum2
           from table2
           GROUP BY ID
           )b
  ON a.ID = b.ID
```

`FULL JOIN` or `FULL OUTER JOIN` will return records from each side of the join whether they join or not. `COALESCE()` returns the first non-NULL value from the list of parameters you supply it.

Alternatively, you could `UNION` the two sets prior to aggregating:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Column1) AS Sum
FROM (Select ID, Column1
      FROM table1
      UNION ALL 
      Select ID, Column1
      FROM table2
      ) sub
GROUP BY ID
```